# Add message to message_post odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I need insert message to message_post.
This source work fine when call from current module:

```py
self.message_post(body="TEXT")
```

Now I want after close wizard insert message to my custom module.

I'm try add below code in wizad .py file but not working.

```py
my_val = self.env['my.module'].search([('id','=',2)])
my_val.write({
    'message_post': "Text Text"
})
```

Any solution?

Comment: if it work with self.message_post why it's not working with may_val.message_post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call **message post** method from wizard.

Ex:

```
my_val = self.env['my.module'].search([('id','=',2)])
my_val.message_post(body="TEXT")
```

This may help you.